# WebMarkupMin + Razor + React: Can not apply markup minification to text content, that was encoded in the 'gzip' format

Tags: c#, asp.net, reactjs, .net-5

I am using a mixture of React.js SPA generate pages and Razor views in an 'ASP.NET Core with React.js' project.

When implementing WebMarkupMin, the following exception occurs at runtime:

> An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
>
> InvalidOperationException: Can not apply markup minification to text content, that was encoded in the 'gzip' format.

[image: Exception Screenshot]

Why is this happening and how can I prevent it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The exception is occurring because WebMarkupMin is trying to minify already-compressed data.

The page is already being compressed by Node.Js ('npm start').

To solve this you can exclude your React.js SPA URLs from WebMarkupMin like this:

```
var reactUrls = new List<IUrlMatcher>(){ new ExactUrlMatcher("/")};
services.AddWebMarkupMin()
            .AddHtmlMinification(options => options.ExcludedPages = reactUrls)
            .AddHttpCompression(options => options.ExcludedPages = reactUrls);
```

In order to point your React.js routes to the ASP.NET managed Razor Views (which are processed by WebMarkupMin) you can do the following:

```
render() {
    const reload = () => window.location.reload();
    return (
        <Switch>
            <Route exact path='/razor' onEnter={reload} />
            <Route exact path='/mvc' onEnter={reload} />
            <Route exact path='/' component={HomePage} />                   
            <Route component={NotFoundPage} />
            <Route path='' onEnter={reload} />
        </Switch>           
    );
```